# I have a main app that I want to store score integer using SharedPreferences

Tags: android

When the app is restarted it returns the default value instead of the
 previously saved value. I need some help.
The main problem here is that I have followed the steps that sharedpreferences demands, the is saved but cannot be restored on app re-open.

The default value in returned when the app is re opened ie
`Score=myScore.getInt ( "score",0 );`

Here is the sample of the score
app code.

```
package tips.admin.tipsscore.score;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  TextView score;
Button add,sub;
Context context;
int Score=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_main );
        score=(TextView)findViewById ( R.id.score );
        add=(Button)findViewById ( R.id.increase );
        sub=(Button)findViewById ( R.id.decrease );
        SharedPreferences myScore=context.getSharedPreferences ("myscore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Score=myScore.getInt ( "score",0 );
        score.setText ( "SCORE :  "+Score );
        add.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Score+=45;
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences ("myscore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPreferences.edit ();
                editor.putInt ( "SCORE :  ",Score);
                editor.commit ();
                score.setText ( "SCORE :  "+Score );

            }
        } );
        sub.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Score-=21;
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences ("myscore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPreferences.edit ();
                editor.putInt ( "SCORE :   ",Score);
                editor.commit ();
                score.setText ( "SCORE :  "+Score );
           }
       } );
   }
```

}

Comment: Your key _(SCORE :  & score)_ is different while save and retrieve your score.

Comment: the key, at save time you used "SCORE :  " but at get time you used "score". The key must be same and also it is case sensitive..

Comment: Just to clarify Piyush comment: you are saving a value under `"SCORE :   "` key, but retrieving a value under `"score"` key

Comment: SCORE : & score , i never thought of that.thank you peoples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You using a different keys for saving and restroring value from shared preferences.
You need to use a same key.

For example:

save:

`editor.putInt ("score_value", Score)`;

read:

```
myScore.getInt ("score_value", 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use string constants instead, to avoid misspelling your tags.

In your class declare :

```
private static final String NAME_OF_TAG = “name_of_tag”
```

Then use that string instead:

```
editor.putInt(NAME_OF_TAG, 3);

int value = preferences.getInt(NAME_OF_TAG, 0);
```